# How to make Report Viewer in asp.net open in pdf Direct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, reportviewer

I Have a ReportViewer that is work 100%, but I need it to open in PDF direct

and there is a sample of my code where I'm binding the reportviewer with the data.

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportDataSource source = new ReportDataSource("dsGetTrnsactions", dt);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(source);
ReportViewer1.DataBind();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the byte array that rappresents the PDF file then you need to open a new window with PDF file. Try this:

```
byte[] file = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(some parameters);

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=Test.pdf");
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.BinaryWrite(file);
Response.End();
```